# DataMapper wont save entries because of under-the-hood validation

Tags: ruby, datamapper

I need pages to be attached to layouts only when users opting for this.

I mean when users editing pages, there are a dropdown to select layout from.

It works well if some layout selected.

However if user selecting `<option value='0'> None` option,
DataMapper throw an error saying `layout_id` should be greater than zero.

I think this **should not happen cause i set `required: false` on `belongs_to :layout`** association.

Here are my models:

```
class Layout

  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String

end

class Page

  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String

  belongs_to :layout, required: false

end
```

Comment: When you submit that form, what does the controller look like?

Comment: not sure what you mean. what controller has to do with model?

Comment: oh, you mean the action that receives data and sending it to DataMapper? It is a trivial method like: `row = DataMapper.first_or_create(id: id).update!(params)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You right about "under-the-hood" validation.

It is automatically added by `belong_to` association.

And you can get rid of it by redefining `layout_id` property.

In `Page` model simply add:

```
property :layout_id, Integer, index: true
```

This will keep the association but will redefine `layout_id` property
so it wont have automatically added validations on it.

However note that this will work only after `Page.auto_migrate!`

Or you can manually remove foreign key from your pages table.

Also, make sure `layout_id` is a index, otherwise you'll have performance issues.

Comment: btw, where is my working demo? i see most of your answers has a live demo attached :)